# Showing measurement units in a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to add measurement units to a `tibble` column and display it when the `tibble` is printed? So, in the following example, is it possible to print `lbs` next to `<dbl>` in the `weight` column?

```r
dplyr::tibble(name = c("Tom", "Jerry"), weight = c(10, 1))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   name  weight
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 Tom       10
#> 2 Jerry      1
```

Comment: You can create a `units` object, such as with `units::set_units`

Comment: The `units` package may be helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/units/vignettes/units.html

Comment: Thanks, @camille and @Brian!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by @camille and @Brian, you can use the `units` library.

Using `valid_udunits()`, you can look up the valid units and find the one you need:

```
   symbol symbol_aliases name_singular name_singular_a… name_plural name_plural_ali… def  
   <chr>  <chr>          <chr>         <chr>            <chr>       <chr>            <chr>
 1 m      ""             meter         metre            ""          ""               ""   
 2 kg     ""             kilogram      ""               ""          ""               ""   
 3 s      ""             second        ""               ""          ""               ""   
 4 A      ""             ampere        ""               ""          ""               ""   
 5 K      ""             kelvin        ""               ""          ""               ""   
 6 mol    ""             mole          ""               ""          ""               ""   
 7 cd     ""             candela       ""               ""          ""               ""   
 8 rad    ""             radian        ""               ""          ""               ""   
 9 sr     ""             steradian     ""               ""          ""               rad^2
10 Hz     ""             hertz         ""               ""          ""               1/s
```

In this case:

```
valid_udunits() %>%
 filter_all(any_vars(. == "pound"))

  symbol symbol_aliases name_singular name_singular_a… name_plural name_plural_ali… def  
  <chr>  <chr>          <chr>         <chr>            <chr>       <chr>            <chr>
1 lb     ""             avoirdupois_… pound            ""          ""               4.53…
```

Then, you can use `set_units()`, which is "a pipe friendly version of `units()`":

```
df %>%
 mutate(weight = set_units(weight, lb))

  name  weight
  <chr>   [lb]
1 Tom       10
2 Jerry      1
```